# Crosswalk Cordova does not build with Android 4.0.3

Tags: crosswalk-runtime

I need to target older device with a cordova application and hope that https://crosswalk-project.org/ will help to solve compatibility issue with older webviews

I followed the instructions in https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application/migrate-using-adt

xwalk_core_library and Cordova does **not build for Android 4.0.3** (API 15)

I tried

- crosswalk-cordova-5.34.104.4-x86
- crosswalk-cordova-6.35.131.7-x86
- crosswalk-cordova-7.35.144.0-x86

none of them are working,

It does build fine with Android 4.4.2 (API 19)

I saw [Crosswalk Cordova does not build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069156/crosswalk-cordova-does-not-build) question and answer but answer solve latest android version and not for Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crosswalk no longer supports Android 4.0.3.
(Despite online documentation,) when you install the plugin (in cordova) you will be advised ICS no longer supported - earliest Android supported is 4.1 (Jellybean) at the time of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Crosswalk Apps supports Android 4.0 and the above. Crosswalk Cordova App built by higher Android SDK should just work on Android 4.0.3 as well,  The App itself doesn't have to be built by Android 4.0.3.

if you have future questions,  you are welcome to visit the follow link for more timely feedback..
https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/community